# How to override a field template using Symfony4 + EasyAdminBundle on Windows?

Tags: windows, symfony4, easyadmin

I'm having a weird problem here. I'm developing an application using Symfony4 and EasyAdminBundle.

I'm developing on a Linux Box but the system has to run on a Windows Box.

This is the configuration I have:

```
easy_admin:
entities:
    # List the entity class name you want to manage
    Banco:
        class: 'App\Entity\Banco'
        label: 'Bancos'
        show:
            title: '%%entity_name%%'
            fields: [ 'nombre', { property: 'saldos', label: 'Saldos', template: 'saldos.html.twig' }, 'movimientos' ]
```

In both my local computer and the client's computer I'm using php's built-in server (The app is only going to be used by one user at the moment).

When I bring the server up on my computer I see:

[image: Screenshot from my computer]

Which is exactly what I want to see.

When I run it from my client's computer I see:

[image]

Which is the default version (Meaning, ignoring the **template** part of the field configuration).

I've already flushed the cache (On windows) and tried a few things (Like moving the template up a level in the dir structure and change the value to 'src/Resources/views/easy_admin/Banco/saldos.html.twig' but neither worked).

I guess it has something to do with file management on Linux vs. Windows, but I can't get around it.

Thanks!